# How to find posts of a facebook page within a certain period of time?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to import posts of a page between 07-12-2017 and 10-12-2017.

I have converted the dates to unix timestamps.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/ekantipur?fields=posts.until(1512926148).limit(125)&access_token=MyAccessToken
```

works and so does

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/ekantipur?fields=posts.since(1512666948).limit(125)&access_token=MyAccessToken
```

But since and until together does not work. It only shows a single id. 
Is there an another way to accomplish this task? If yes please reply. Thankyou in advance.

> **Update** here is my updated Url with since and until. Its still not working.

```
123456/posts?since=07-12-2017&until=10-12-2017
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you update the original post with your combined Since and Until?

I'm assuming that the SINCE is set to 7/17 and the UNTIL is 10/17, correct?  It looks that way from the converted numbers, but I try not to assume it isn't something small like that :).  No offense intended.

Looking at the graph API, I am using the page id of one I am the admin of and using since and until and it's coming back with posts between 07-12-2017 and 10-12-2017.  I'm wondering if it has something to do with the limit in your urls.  What if the limit statements are narrowing things down too much?

I'm just putting this into the graph API and getting the results I'm expecting: (no, my page id isn't 123456)

[image: no, my page id is not 123456]

Granted, I'm not calling it in a url, Graph API is pretty forgiving.

Comment: updated the url in the original post. Please have a look

Comment: Thanks for updating that.  Here's my whole url, with the page number changed and the token removed.  <https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/123456/posts?since=07-12-2017&until=10-12-2017&access_token=MYACCESSTOKEN>


couple of things - I am the admin of this page, so my token is a page token.  I found that if I set it up right in Graph API and then hit the Get Code button and copy the CURL statement, the url I needed was there.  Does it work with until/since in Graph API?  If so, try getting the url from the curl button.